# Python global name error

Tags: python

that program does not work, I wanna do a binary search but just in the start it gives me global error. It says "search" is not defined. Please help me out with this my whole lecture is stuck with it.

```
def bsearch (s, e, first, last):
  print first, last
  if (last - first) < 2: return s[first] == e or s[last] == e
  mid = (last - first) + (last - first)/2
  if s[mid] == e: return True
  if s[mid] > e: return bsearch(s, e, first, mid - 1)
  return bsearch(s, e, mid + 1, last)

def search1 (s, e):
  print bsearch(s, e, 0, len(s) - 1)
  print 'Search complete'

def testSearch():
  s = range(0,1000000)
  raw_input('basic, -1')
  print search(s,-1)
  raw_input('binary, -1')
  print search1(s,-1)
  raw_input('basic, end')
  print search(s,1000000)
  raw_input('binary, end')
  print search1(s,1000000)
  s = range(0,10000000)
  raw_input('basic, partway')
  print search(s,1000000)
  raw_input('basic, larger end')
  print search(0,10000000)

>>> testSearch()
basic, -1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    testSearch()
  File "C:\Users\bangash\Documents\python files\lec8.py", line 17, in testSearch
    print search(s,-1)
NameError: global name 'search' is not defined
```

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my answer then??

Comment: Please don't destroy your own questions; that makes the answers a lot less useful.  (Here the question might have been too localized to be much use anyway, but the rules against self-vandalism are well-established.)

Comment: some of em sitting around here are phsycopaths,,dont even know how to behave,,,and giving their own perception about how i am behaving. Just delete it please. will ya??

Answer (score 1):

Your testcases seem to be comparing the performance of `search` and `search1`

So I imagine `search` is supposed to be a linear (ie basic) search function that you haven't defined yet

for example:

```
def search(s, e):
    for item in s:
        if item == e:
            break
    print 'Search complete'
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont see where you define `search` but you do assign `search1` as a function do you have the names mistaken?

just change all the `search(s,-1)` lines to `search1(s,-1)`

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, you'll just be running the same testcases twice